# attr() of html data attribute returns undefined

Tags: jquery, svg, jquery-selectors, custom-data-attribute

I have some SVG like this

```
<circle cx="750.03201548" cy="174.107626293" data-code="NY" data-name="New York" data-population="8175133" r="16"></circle>
```

When I try to get cx value like this, it returns 'undefined'

```
var locCX = $('[data-code="NY"]').attr('cx');
console.log(locCX);
```

Any Ideas what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:

Ok written like above it works, I have translated this example. My original SVG looks like this. Sorry for confusion.

```
<circle cx="750.03201548" cy="174.107626293" data-code="Pisek" data-name="Písek" data-population="8175133" r="16"></circle>
```

When I try to get cx value like this, it returns 'undefined'

```
var locCX = $('[data-name="Písek"]').attr('cx');
console.log(locCX);
```

Now this doesnt work, with regional character " í ".

Comment: You code works just fine for me

Comment: Check that the svg has been loaded before trying to get its cx attribute

Comment: sorry I used bad example, question now edited

Comment: @Houdasek that still works for me, use the snippet tool and create an example is the "not working" as it shall

Answer (score 0):

I have foud the problem at duplicate data-name attribute in SVG. Thanks everybody for your time.